# OWASP Juice-Shop Error

Tags: security, application-launch, parrot-os

I have followed all of the steps to install and start [Juice-Shop](https://www2.owasp.org/www-project-juice-shop/). I believe I have installed all necessary dependencies; vagrant and vagrant file is present in the directory, yet these error messages appear:

PRETTY_NAME="Parrot GNU/Linux 4.7"
last update 10/28/19

nfo: All dependencies in ./package.json are satisfied (OK)
info: Detected Node.js version v12.13.0 (OK)
info: Detected OS linux (OK)
info: Detected CPU x64 (OK)
info: Required file index.html is present (OK)
info: Required file styles.css is present (OK)
info: Required file main-es2015.js is present (OK)
info: Required file polyfills-es2015.js is present (OK)
info: Required file runtime-es2015.js is present (OK)
info: Required file vendor-es2015.js is present (OK)
info: Required file main-es5.js is present (OK)
info: Required file polyfills-es5.js is present (OK)
info: Required file runtime-es5.js is present (OK)
info: Required file vendor-es5.js is present (OK)
info: Configuration default validated (OK)
(node:2711) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EACCES: permission denied, copyfile '/home/daft/juice-shop/data/static/legal.md' -> '/home/daft/juice-shop/ftp/legal.md'
    at Object.copyFileSync (fs.js:1790:3)
    at restoreOverwrittenFilesWithOriginals (/home/daft/juice-shop/lib/startup/restoreOverwrittenFilesWithOriginals.js:7:6)
    at Object. (/home/daft/juice-shop/server.js:122:62)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at /home/daft/juice-shop/app.js:2:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:2711) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2711) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
info: Port 3000 is available (OK)

Comment: you may find additional wisdom at https://pwning.owasp-juice.shop/ , https://groups.google.com/a/owasp.org/forum/#!forum/juice-shop-project , https://owasp.slack.com/?redir=%2Fmessages%2Fproject-juiceshop , https://www.reddit.com/r/owasp_juiceshop/ , and https://gitter.im/bkimminich/juice-shop .  Also, question editing tips are at http://superuser.com/editing-help#code

Comment: thanks for your assistance, I will look into the above resources.